# Git - Reset commit in master or cherry-pick / merge to sync up master's commit to other branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-reset, git-cherry-pick

Initially I have `master` and `develop` branch at the same state, but I accidently make some commits directly to the `master`.

Now I'm going to sync the `master`'s commit to `develop`, but our practices is branch out `feature` from `develop` and make changes to the `feature` and then PR to the `develop`.

So I branched out a `feature` branch ***sync_up_develop_with_master*** and planned to cherry-pick the `master`'s commit into this feature branch.

[image]

But I read some articles which says **merge** is preferable over **cherry-pick** (due to SHA1 identifier).
or should I just **reset** the commit in `master` since it's just minor changes.

Can anyone suggest me the correct approach on my case?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation: from branch `develop`, you can run

```
# from branch develop
git merge --autostash --ff-only master
```

and `develop` will be updated.

---

`--autostash` will handle the `git stash / git stash pop` around your merge operation to port your uncommitted changes

`--ff-only` makes sure that `git merge` will perform only fast-forward actions. That way you are 100% certain that this command will not accidentally create an unwanted merge commit.